# Error checking on many function calls

Tags: c++, c, recursion, error-handling

Sometimes when I am programming in C++/C I end up calling the same function multiple times and I was wondering what is the most efficient way to check for errors for all of those calls? Using `if else` statements take up a lot of code and look ugly. I have come up with my own way of checking for errors, perhaps there is a better way that I should use.

```
int errs[5] = {0};
errs[0] = functiona(...);
errs[1] = functiona(...);
...
errs[5] = functiona(...);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  if (err[i] == 0)
     MAYDAY!_wehaveanerror();
}
```

Note: I understand that using `try` and `catch` might be better for C++ as it would solve this problem by throwing an exception on the first error, but the problem with that is that it is not compatible with a lot of functions that return error codes such as the Windows API. Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to know as soon as possible when an error occurred, and check each return code as you get it?  Using your method, you could generate a sequence of errors, and only find out about the first.

Comment: Iterate over the list of paramaters you will pass, call the function with that iteration's parameters, set a "we have an error" bool to true the first time an error is detected, and terminate the loop right then and there.

Comment: Additionally: Just because a Windows API function only returns error codes doesn't mean you can't throw upon receiving an error code.

Comment: @ScottHunter I would like to do that which is why I am asking my question about how to find a neat way to do it. My code calls the same function `GetPrivateProfileStringA` about 40 times to load the settings for my program. That means there are 40 `if` statements and 40 `then` statements plus the handler which is very ugly.

Comment: @user99545: *Note: This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications. Applications should store initialization information in the registry.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If...IF the function has a chance to throw a different error you should also add a catch all.

```
struct my_exception : public std::exception {
    my_exception(int); /* ... */ };

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int e;
        if ((e = function()) != SUCCESS) { throw my_exception(e); }
        if ((e = function()) != SUCCESS) { throw my_exception(e); }
        if ((e = function()) != SUCCESS) { throw my_exception(e); }
    }
    catch (my_exception & e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Something went wrong: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        //Error Checking
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could write some pseudo-C++ like this:

```
struct my_exception : public std::exception {
    my_exception(int); /* ... */ };

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int e;
        if ((e = function()) != SUCCESS) { throw my_exception(e); }
        if ((e = function()) != SUCCESS) { throw my_exception(e); }
        if ((e = function()) != SUCCESS) { throw my_exception(e); }
    }
    catch (my_exception & e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Something went wrong: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could wrap the Windows API function with a thin layer that converts the error codes into exceptions. Borland Delphi had done this 15 years ago, it worked great and still works great.

Answer (score 1):

What about handling the checking in a function?

```
void my_function() {
  if (!create_window())
    throw Error("Failed to create window");
}

int main() {
  try {
    my_function();
  } catch (const Error& e) {
    cout << e.msg << endl;
  } catch (...) {
    cout << "Unknown exception caught\n"
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling the same function over and over again, the most succinct way might be to use a macro.  I would suggest something like:

```
#define CHECKERROR(x) if(x == 0) wehaveanerror()

CHECKERROR(function(...));
CHECKERROR(function(...));
```

Obviously, this macro would be very specific to the particular function and error handler involved, so it may be prudent to `undef` it after those calls.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it more old-school, but keeping w/ the original error response but responding as soon as an error occurs w/o looking ugly:

```
#define callcheck(r) if ((r)==0) MAYDAY!_wehaveanerror()

callcheck(functiona(...));
callcheck(functiona(...));
...
```